# Make sure validation range value doesn't overlap with existing ranges with sql-server and C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have some range information stored in a database as `from_amount` and `to_amount`  as given below,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7rpA.png]

```
public List<int> CheckRange(decimal from, decimal to)
{
    var rets = new List<int>();

    // Check From Amount
    if (Entity.amount.Any(x => x.to_amount >= from))
        rets.Add(1);

    // Check To Amount
    if (Entity.amount.Any(x => x.from_amount <= to))
        rets.Add(2);           
    return rets;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Almost always better to use *inclusive* start points and *exclusive* end points for these types of ranges. Makes it much easier when start and end values (of different ranges) should match up - let's you see that you've not covered 5000.01 - 5999.99, nor 10000.01 - 10000.99, for example.

Comment: how to make a query in C #, so that the input data does not overlap with existing data

Answer (score 1):

Try this condition in `Where` method:

```
.Where(e => !((e.from_amount > from && e.from_amount < to) 
                || (e.to_amount > from && e.to_amount < to) 
                || (e.from_amount < from && e.to_amount > to)));
```

first two conditinons makes sure that no boundary is inside given range, so it leaves only with one option, when one range is included inside the other, but third condition checks that (obviously, conditions check opposite of what I said, that's why the negation at the beginning).

NOTE: You might want to change `<`, `>` operators to `<=` and `>=`